# Drop down widget with detail showing on pressing this dropdown in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, package, dropdown, code-snippets

How can i make a drop down widget like showing in picture.

[image]

On pressing the drop down button, we have to show details related to that button only. Can any one share some repository/dart package or code snippet to achieve that in flutter

Comment: for me it is not really clear what you want to do. Where do you want to show the picture? A DropdownButton basically contains two builder: the "selectedItemBuilder" which is responsible for the content when the dropdownbutton is not clicked (here I assume Text(date)) and the items array where you define which widgets are shown in the overlay when you click the dropdownbutton.

Comment: I am just trying to achieve this kind of functionality like when i press the date button, the button will expand one at a time and show me the relative details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/expandable 
With `controller`, you can manually set `expanded` to `false` or `true` 
So you can achieve collapse others

code snippet

```
List<ExpandableController> controllerList = [
  ExpandableController(),
  ExpandableController(),
  ExpandableController()
];

 ExpandablePanel(
            controller: controllerList[2],

 for (int i = 0; i < controllerList.length; i++) {
      if (i == currentIndex) {
        controllerList[i].expanded = true;
      } else {
        controllerList[i].expanded = false;
      }
    }

 ScrollOnExpand(
      scrollOnExpand: true,
      scrollOnCollapse: false,
      child: ExpandablePanel(
        theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
          ...
        header: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ...
        collapsed: Container(),
        expanded: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:expandable/expandable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Expandable Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() {
    return MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Expandable Demo"),
      ),
      body: ExpandableTheme(
        data: const ExpandableThemeData(
          iconColor: Colors.blue,
          useInkWell: true,
        ),
        child: ListView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          children: <Widget>[
            Card1(),
            Card2(),
            Card3(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const loremIpsum =
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

List<ExpandableController> controllerList = [
  ExpandableController(),
  ExpandableController(),
  ExpandableController()
];

int currentIndex = -1;

class Card1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpandableNotifier(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.blue,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ScrollOnExpand(
              scrollOnExpand: true,
              scrollOnCollapse: false,
              child: ExpandablePanel(
                controller: controllerList[0],
                theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
                  iconColor: Colors.white,
                  headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
                  tapBodyToCollapse: true,
                ),
                header: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    currentIndex = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < controllerList.length; i++) {
                      if (i == currentIndex) {
                        controllerList[i].expanded = true;
                      } else {
                        controllerList[i].expanded = false;
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.calendar_today,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                )),
                            Expanded(flex: 1, child: Container()),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 4,
                              child: Text(
                                "15/06/2020",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                collapsed: Container(),
                expanded: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text("Bill Date",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                            Text("15/05/2020",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          thickness: 2.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Adjustment",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                            Text(".00", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          thickness: 2.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text("Total due",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                            Text("413.27",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                builder: (_, collapsed, expanded) {
                  return Expandable(
                    collapsed: collapsed,
                    expanded: expanded,
                    theme: const ExpandableThemeData(crossFadePoint: 0),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class Card2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpandableNotifier(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.blue,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ScrollOnExpand(
              scrollOnExpand: true,
              scrollOnCollapse: false,
              child: ExpandablePanel(
                controller: controllerList[1],
                theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
                  iconColor: Colors.white,
                  headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
                  tapBodyToCollapse: true,
                ),
                header: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    currentIndex = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < controllerList.length; i++) {
                      if (i == currentIndex) {
                        controllerList[i].expanded = true;
                      } else {
                        controllerList[i].expanded = false;
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.calendar_today,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                )),
                            Expanded(flex: 1, child: Container()),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 4,
                              child: Text(
                                "15/05/2020",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                collapsed: Container(),
                expanded: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text("Bill Date",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                            Text("15/06/2020",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          thickness: 2.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Adjustment",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                            Text(".00", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          thickness: 2.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text("Total due",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                            Text("413.27",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                builder: (_, collapsed, expanded) {
                  return Expandable(
                    collapsed: collapsed,
                    expanded: expanded,
                    theme: const ExpandableThemeData(crossFadePoint: 0),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class Card3 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpandableNotifier(
        child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.blue,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ScrollOnExpand(
              scrollOnExpand: true,
              scrollOnCollapse: false,
              child: ExpandablePanel(
                controller: controllerList[2],
                theme: const ExpandableThemeData(
                  iconColor: Colors.white,
                  headerAlignment: ExpandablePanelHeaderAlignment.center,
                  tapBodyToCollapse: true,
                ),
                header: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    currentIndex = 2;
                    for (int i = 0; i < controllerList.length; i++) {
                      if(i == currentIndex) {
                        controllerList[i].expanded = true;
                      } else {
                        controllerList[i].expanded = false;
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.calendar_today,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                )),
                            Expanded(flex: 1, child: Container()),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 4,
                              child: Text(
                                "14/04/2020",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
                collapsed: Container(),
                expanded: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text("Bill Date",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                            Text("15/05/2020",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          thickness: 2.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Adjustment",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                            Text(".00", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          thickness: 2.0,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text("Total due",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                            Text("413.27",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                builder: (_, collapsed, expanded) {
                  return Expandable(
                    collapsed: collapsed,
                    expanded: expanded,
                    theme: const ExpandableThemeData(crossFadePoint: 0),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: In this how can we handle that only one widget expanded at a time. Like if we already have a widget that is expanded and we press another widget to expand, i want to shrink the previous widget first and expand this new widget which user tap now

Comment: Yes, i accepted your answer. It is working perfectly. 
Thankyou for the support

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using expansion tile which allows you to define header and expanded content. See this [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-expansion-collapse-view-fde9c51ac438) for detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-expansion-collapse-view-fde9c51ac438) David posted is a very good explanation!
Try out

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Expansionpanel extends StatefulWidget {
  Expansionpaneltate createState() =>  Expansionpaneltate();
}
class NewItem {
  bool isExpanded;
  final String header;
  final Widget body;
  final Icon iconpic;
  NewItem(this.isExpanded, this.header, this.body, this.iconpic);
}
class Expansionpaneltate extends State<Expansionpanel> {
  List<NewItem> items = <NewItem>[
    NewItem(
      false, // isExpanded ?
      '14.04.2020', // here are your dates.
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('data'),
            Text('data'),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('data'),
                Text('data'),
                Text('data'),
              ],
            ),
            Radio(value: null, groupValue: null, onChanged: null)
          ]
        )
      ), // body
      Icon(Icons.image) // iconPic
    ),
  ];
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    Scaffold scaffold =  Scaffold(
      appBar:  AppBar(
        title:  Text("ExpansionPanelList"),
      ),
      body: ListView(
      children: [
         Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: ExpansionPanelList(
            expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
              setState(() {
                items[index].isExpanded = !items[index].isExpanded;
              });
            },
            children: items.map((NewItem item) {
              return ExpansionPanel(
                headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                  return  ListTile(
                    leading: item.iconpic,
                    title:  Text(
                      item.header,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style:  TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      ),
                    )
                  );
                },
                isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
                body: item.body,
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );,
    );
    return scaffold;
  }
}
```